# How do you deserialize json into the correct virtual class?

Tags: apex, generics, json

Let's say I have a virtual class and two classes that extend it and I am getting a JSON response that could be either one of those classes. Is there a way to deserialize the JSON into the appropriate class without examining it manually?

Here are my classes:

```
public with sharing virtual class BaseClass
{
public Integer id;
}

public with sharing class foo extends BaseClass
{
public String foo;
}

public with sharing class bar extends BaseClass
{
public Integer bar;
}
```

I want to be able to do something like

```
Json.deserialize(jsonstring,Class.BaseClass.Descendants)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your JSON always has an `id`, but also has either a `foo` or a `bar`, I think the corresponding Apex would be

```
public class Thing {
    public Integer id;
    public String foo;
    public Integer bar;
}
```

You would deserialize into a `Thing`, then test whether foo or bar was null. There's no way to persuade the parser to pick the correct subclass.

Comment: Well, my actual scenario is that my base class has a few fields and the classes extending it each have many fields. 

I am trying to integrate with an API that returns a whole bunch of JSON objects and I was hoping that I could do the JSON deserialization as part of my generic response handler (since all the error handling and such is the same no matter what object I'm getting)

Comment: Is there anything in your data that tells you what kind of object you need to create, before you hit the object itself?

Comment: Yes, the endpoint for each object is different. I.E. /user, /account etc. I can definitely figure out which object to deserialize to. Was just hoping there was some generic way to do this.

Comment: I'm running into this as well.  I can tell which subclass I should be using (there is an attribute field on the object pertaining to the subclass).  @metadaddy is there a way to instantiate the correct subclass this way without writing my own JSON parser?

Comment: No way I know of to get the stock JSON parser to select the correct subclass :-(

Comment: More specifically, when you de-serialize into a virtual class, you're de-serializing *into* a virtual class. The de-serializer doesn't know how to determine which sub-class to use, and there's no known syntax for this. Perhaps for good reason: `public virtual class A { integer x; } public class B extends A { } public class C extends A { }`. All three classes have the same members, but possibly different functions. Which class should JSON de-serialize to?

Answer (score 4):

Based on the responses above, it's just not possible using the JSON.deserialize method.  You have to develop your own parser.  I too had the same requirement, and here's what I came up with.  I'm sure it can be improved, since it's essentially parsing the JSON string 3 times.

In my case, I needed to take a parent QueryResult class, parse the JSON response into the class, but the class had a member variable called 'records'.  This records member variable was a list of virtual classes, extended by 1 of 10 subclasses.

I parsed out the "type" attribute of the first record, which indicates what the subclass is, then used Type.forName() to deserialize the particular JSON token I needed into the correctly typed array.

```
private static QueryResult parseQueryResult(String jsonStr){
    QueryResult queryResult = (QueryResult)JSON.deserialize(jsonStr, ToolingAPI.QueryResult.class);
    queryResult.records = getQueryResultRecords(jsonStr);
    return queryResult;
}

/**
 * Helper method for parsing the QueryResult response and determining
 * which instance of QueryResultRecord to use
 */
private static List<QueryResultRecord> getQueryResultRecords(String jsonStr){

    String recordType = getRecordType(jsonStr);

    if(recordType != null){
        JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(jsonStr);

        while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
            if ((parser.getText() == 'records')) {
                parser.nextToken();
                return (List<QueryResultRecord>)parser.readValueAs(Type.forName('List<ToolingAPI.'+recordType+'>'));
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * Helper method for parsing type attribute from query result records in JSON response
 */
private static String getRecordType(String jsonStr){
    JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(jsonStr);

    while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
        if ((parser.getText() == 'records')) {
            while(parser.nextToken() != null) {
                if(parser.getText() == 'attributes'){
                    while(parser.nextToken() != null){
                        if(parser.getText() == 'type'){
                            //Value of type attribute
                            parser.nextToken();
                            return parser.getText();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Again, this can probably be improved on, but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible.

JSON is a data only object, and has no knowledge of your classes.

You would need to embed the name of your class and check that when de-serializing.

Comment: Is this possible in Apex?  That is, is there an analogue to Java's `instance.getClass().getName()`?

Comment: Answering my own question!  There is `instance.class.getName()` [http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_type.htm ]

Comment: @Benj sadly .class.getName() doesn't work on the instance, it works on the class as if "class" were a static property. I'm not aware of any way to get a System.Type object from an actual instance of a class, only from the class itself.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [`Json.deserializeStrict`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_System_Json_deserializeStrict.htm) to attempt each class? If your `type` lacks the necessary fields it will throw a `System.JsonException` which you can catch then attempt the next type?

eg:

```
List<Type> types = new List<Type>{
    BaseClass.class,
    Foo.class,
    Bar.class
};

BaseClass value;
for (Type t : types) {
    try {
        value = (BaseClass)Json.deserializeStrict(jsonstring, t);
    } catch (JsonException e) {
        continue;
    }
}

if (t instanceof Bar) ...
else if (t instanceof Foo) ...
else if (t instanceof BaseClass) ...
```